# Linux SSH access control

Tags: ssh

I want to allow anyone access to SSH with a valid identity key BUT allow only one IP address to have SSH password access.

How do I do this?

(I'm running on Centos 5.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use the `Match` statement (see [sshd_config(5)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5)) to distinguish between clients and allow exactly one client (e. g. identified by its IP address) to log in with its password rather than having an SSH key.

Comment: I only want to allow 1 IP to use SSH password ... but I want that IP (and any other) to be able to use identity key login as well. Can I do this with a Match statement?

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. The man page `sshd_config(8)` mentions explicitly which directives you can use in a `Match` block. But be aware to put the `Match` directive and the following directives *at the end* of your `sshd_config` file.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Security/linux_pam.shtml#News

Modify pam to do this. I never try this.

Comment: Go the PAM route.

Comment: Don't! It's a trap! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could run 2 sshd's

1 - run normally from init, key authentication only (set in sshd_config)

2 - run from xinetd (http://www.itech7.com/Linux/How-to-configure-SSHD-on-Xinetd) listening on a different port (eg 2222) with a separate sshd_config etc and that port is configured with your local firewall (iptables / whatever) to only allow access from the IP you want.